# What is the most important attribute of a project manager/team leader you expect?

Tags: language-agnostic, project-management

Just read [Joel on Software - How to be a program manager](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/03/09.html).

In his article he points out different things for a program manager.

> - ...(in fact, with 14 years of programming experience, you might know
>     too much to be a good user advocate
> - ...earn the respect of the programmers so that they concede that you’re right
> - ...It helps, as a program manager, to be pretty good at coding yourself
> - ...demonstrate intelligence, open-mindedness, and fairness in any debates

What do you, as the perfect audience to vote for this question, think.
What attributes of a project manager are in your opinion

1. indispensable
2. less important
3. needless
4. inoperative

to have.

Comment: The "/" between "project manager/team leader" should be seen as "or". Should I have written it as "||" ;-) It shall not imply to be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO the most important skill of a PM is sheilding developers from the politics of the job. If the customer (whether that be internal or external) is interfering with the developer's productivity then the PM isnt doing their job.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that the ability to remove roadblocks from the path of the developers before they become problems is the single most important aspect of this type of management.

Having a clear, well defined path for development allows devs to find their flow state without having to switch or stop.

Answer (score 6):

A project manager who understands that software estimations are NOT the deadline.

Comment: Heh. A good PM should have contingency time built into the plan. A deadline may be fixed by an outside influence (beyond the control of the PM); in which case the PM can only reduce the work; or increase the workers. It may also be an arbitrary deadline, but the result is the same.

Comment: Increasing workers doesn't always solve the deadline problem. It can even make it worse if they get lost in details, because of "too much knowledge".

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the project manager and the team leader are not the same person. In fact, I've never had a project manager as my team lead in the 15 years I've been in IT.

To answer your question, what I look for in a **team leader**:

- Compassion
- Empathy
- Knowledge of the
  business
- Knowledge of the technology
  we're using
- Patience
- Good mentoring
  skills
- Good listening skills

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion a good project manager / team leader is able to act as grease between customer, management and developer, advocates for each party if needed (not just management), and deals with obstacles that prevent the project from moving forward so developers can focus on developing.

Answer (score 1):

A nice management method, which I like, is MBWA (not to be mixed up with MBA). This means management by walking around. It can sound a bit weird but think of it...

Look at this link (as one of many available out there): http://www.businesstown.com/people/communication-walking.asp

...and of cause this doesn't work for every manager and project there is...

Comment: Sound like Lumbergh!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I hate to tell you this, but the most important attribute is their Communication ability; hands down. If they can't communicate well they can't remove road blocks, and they can't translate between the stakeholders and the doers.

Communication is shortly followed by organisation/planning ability and tool knowledge; and of course by domain knowledge (B.S. detector, and a general understanding of the project without having to ask... what's that all the time.)

Without these three things, you are at a disadvantage.

So, I agree with Joel, that having a background in programming is essential for a Project Manager/ Program Manager - especially with intangible things like software. However, do you have to have 10 or 15 years experience? No. a couple years on the floor should clue you in enough.

Comment: What happens if the team lead is a BS'er? ...

Comment: The PM is Ultimately responsible for the project. If they are BSing, chances are the project will fail (in one or more ways). When projects fail badly, the PM tends to shuffled off somewhere where they can do no harm (be it a simpler project or the employment office).

Answer (score 0):

The ability to tell good from bad, that we casually refer to as "quality". Everything else just follows.

Answer (score 0):

Team leader:

- Communication
- Ability to lead/drive the team (so many can't)
- Ability to code and understand any piece of code written by any team member
- Should never lie about his experience level (my case currently, cant trust the decisions he makes to be correct...)